# WSS4J and PCKS11 keystore

Tags: java, soap, sign, wss4j

I'm trying to use PKCS11 keystone (smart card) with WSS4J. I have code for creating keystone from smart card and another code for singing SOAP message with WSS4J using keystone from file. Problem is how to "merge" them.

PKCS11 keystore:

```
    String pin = "1111";
    char[] pin_arr = pin.toCharArray();
    String pkcs11config = "name = SmartCard\n"  + "library = c:/windows/system32/aetpkss1.dll";
    byte[] pkcs11configBytes = pkcs11config.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
    Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
    Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

    KeyStore smartCardKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");

    smartCardKeyStore.load(null, pin_arr);
```

WSS4J signing code:

```
    public Document signSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage soapEnvelope)
        throws SOAPException, TransformerException, WSSecurityException {
    Source src = soapEnvelope.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    transformer.transform(src, result);
    Document doc = (Document) result.getNode();

    final RequestData reqData = new RequestData();
    java.util.Map msgContext = new java.util.TreeMap();
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENABLE_SIGNATURE_CONFIRMATION, "true");
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.MUST_UNDERSTAND, "false");
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "sender.properties");
    String bodyPart = "{Content}{}Body";
    String thumbprintPart = "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}BinarySecurityToken";
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, bodyPart + ";" + thumbprintPart);
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENABLE_SIGNATURE_CONFIRMATION, "true");


    // Set this property if you want client public key (X509 certificate) sent along with document
    // server will check signature using this public key
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
    msgContext.put("password", "keystore");
    reqData.setMsgContext(msgContext);
    reqData.setUsername("clientca3");

    final java.util.List actions = new java.util.ArrayList();
    actions.add(new Integer(WSConstants.SIGN));
    CustomHandler handler = new CustomHandler();

    // sign document
    handler.send(WSConstants.SIGN, doc, reqData, actions, true);

    return doc;
}
```

and finally sender.properties file:

```
    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=keystore
    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=clientca3
    org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=C:/temp/keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a "MerlinDevice" Crypto implementation available in WSS4J for this scenario. So, just define the following in your crypto properties file:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.MerlinDevice
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this can work, but you can try... based on your code, first load the pkcs11 provider to Security.

```
public void loadPkcs11(){
    String pkcs11config = "name = SmartCard\n"  + "library = c:/windows/system32/aetpkss1.dll";
    byte[] pkcs11configBytes = pkcs11config.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
    Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
    Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
}
```

Then before you sign the SOAP call loadPkcs11 method, in order that provider will be available when you sign the soap:

```
public Document signSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage soapEnvelope)
    throws SOAPException, TransformerException, WSSecurityException {

    loadPkcs11();

    Source src = soapEnvelope.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    ...
```

And your sender.properties file:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=PKCS11
# provider name, all pkcs11 provider name is "SunPKCS11-" + the value of parameter name in your configuration
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.provider=SunPKCS11-SmartCard
# smartcard pin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=1111
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=
#this param is not required in pkcs11
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

1. Create new class CryptoSmartCard which is a copy of Merlin and extends CryptoBase. Difference between new class and Merlin is in method loadProperties(Properties properties, ClassLoader loader):

   ```
   public void loadProperties(Properties properties, ClassLoader loader)
       throws CredentialException, IOException {
   if (properties == null) {
       return;
   }
   this.properties = properties;
   //
   // Load the provider(s)
   //
   String provider = properties.getProperty(CRYPTO_KEYSTORE_PROVIDER);
   if (provider != null) {
       provider = provider.trim();
   }
   String certProvider = properties.getProperty(CRYPTO_CERT_PROVIDER);
   if (certProvider != null) {
       setCryptoProvider(certProvider);
   }
   //
   // Load the KeyStore
   //
   String alias = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_ALIAS);
   if (alias != null) {
       alias = alias.trim();
       defaultAlias = alias;
   }
   String keyStoreLocation = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_FILE);
   if (keyStoreLocation == null) {
       keyStoreLocation = properties.getProperty(OLD_KEYSTORE_FILE);
   }
   if (keyStoreLocation != null) {
       keyStoreLocation = keyStoreLocation.trim();
       InputStream is = loadInputStream(loader, keyStoreLocation);

       try {
           String passwd = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, "security");
           if (passwd != null) {
               passwd = passwd.trim();
           }
           String type = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_TYPE, KeyStore.getDefaultType());
           if (type != null) {
               type = type.trim();
           }

           String pin = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_PASSWORD);
           char[] pin_arr = pin.toCharArray();
           String pkcs11config = "name = SmartCard\n" + "library = " + properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_FILE);
           byte[] pkcs11configBytes = pkcs11config.getBytes();
           ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
           Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
           try {
               Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

               keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(type,pkcs11Provider);

               keystore.load(null, pin_arr);


           } catch (Exception ex) {
               // nothing
           }
           //keystore = load(is, passwd, provider, type);
           if (DO_DEBUG) {
               LOG.debug(
                       "The KeyStore " + keyStoreLocation + " of type " + type
                       + " has been loaded");
           }
           String privatePasswd = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_PASSWORD);
           if (privatePasswd != null) {
               privatePasswordSet = true;
           }
       } finally {
           if (is != null) {
               is.close();
           }
       }
   } else {
       if (DO_DEBUG) {
           LOG.debug("The KeyStore is not loaded as KEYSTORE_FILE is null");
       }
   }

   //
   // Load the TrustStore
   //
   String trustStoreLocation = properties.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_FILE);
   if (trustStoreLocation != null) {
       trustStoreLocation = trustStoreLocation.trim();
       InputStream is = loadInputStream(loader, trustStoreLocation);

       try {
           String passwd = properties.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, "changeit");
           if (passwd != null) {
               passwd = passwd.trim();
           }
           String type = properties.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_TYPE, KeyStore.getDefaultType());
           if (type != null) {
               type = type.trim();
           }
           truststore = load(is, passwd, provider, type);
           if (DO_DEBUG) {
               LOG.debug(
                       "The TrustStore " + trustStoreLocation + " of type " + type
                       + " has been loaded");
           }
           loadCACerts = false;
       } finally {
           if (is != null) {
               is.close();
           }
       }
   } else {
       String loadCacerts = properties.getProperty(LOAD_CA_CERTS, "false");
       if (loadCacerts != null) {
           loadCacerts = loadCacerts.trim();
       }
       if (Boolean.valueOf(loadCacerts).booleanValue()) {
           String cacertsPath = System.getProperty("java.home") + "/lib/security/cacerts";
           if (cacertsPath != null) {
               cacertsPath = cacertsPath.trim();
           }
           InputStream is = new FileInputStream(cacertsPath);
           try {
               String cacertsPasswd = properties.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD, "changeit");
               if (cacertsPasswd != null) {
                   cacertsPasswd = cacertsPasswd.trim();
               }
               truststore = load(is, cacertsPasswd, null, KeyStore.getDefaultType());
               if (DO_DEBUG) {
                   LOG.debug("CA certs have been loaded");
               }
               loadCACerts = true;
           } finally {
               if (is != null) {
                   is.close();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   //
   // Load the CRL file
   //
   String crlLocation = properties.getProperty(X509_CRL_FILE);
   if (crlLocation != null) {
       crlLocation = crlLocation.trim();
       InputStream is = loadInputStream(loader, crlLocation);

       try {
           CertificateFactory cf = getCertificateFactory();
           X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) cf.generateCRL(is);

           if (provider == null || provider.length() == 0) {
               crlCertStore =
                       CertStore.getInstance(
                       "Collection",
                       new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Collections.singletonList(crl)));
           } else {
               crlCertStore =
                       CertStore.getInstance(
                       "Collection",
                       new CollectionCertStoreParameters(Collections.singletonList(crl)),
                       provider);
           }
           if (DO_DEBUG) {
               LOG.debug(
                       "The CRL " + crlLocation + " has been loaded");
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           if (DO_DEBUG) {
               LOG.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
           }
           throw new CredentialException(CredentialException.IO_ERROR, "ioError00", e);
       } finally {
           if (is != null) {
               is.close();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Only change is in following lines in that method:

```
            String pin = properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_PASSWORD);
            char[] pin_arr = pin.toCharArray();
            String pkcs11config = "name = SmartCard\n" + "library = " + properties.getProperty(KEYSTORE_FILE);
            byte[] pkcs11configBytes = pkcs11config.getBytes();
            ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
            Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
            try {
                Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

                keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(type,pkcs11Provider);

                keystore.load(null, pin_arr);


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // nothing
            }
```

1. After that I'm using that class to create Crypto object manually:

   Crypto crypto = new CryptoSmartCard(prop);

Here is the code for signing method:

```
   public Document signSOAPMessage3(SOAPMessage soapEnvelope)
        throws SOAPException, TransformerException, WSSecurityException, CredentialException, IOException {
    Source src = soapEnvelope.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
    transformer.transform(src, result);
    Document doc = (Document) result.getNode();

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("sender.properties");
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestSignWS1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Crypto crypto = new CryptoSmartCard(prop);

    final RequestData reqData = new RequestData();
    java.util.Map msgContext = new java.util.TreeMap();
    //msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENABLE_SIGNATURE_CONFIRMATION, "true");
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.MUST_UNDERSTAND, "false");
    //msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "sender.properties");
    String bodyPart = "{Content}{}Body";
    String thumbprintPart = "{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}BinarySecurityToken";
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, thumbprintPart + ";" + bodyPart);
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.IS_BSP_COMPLIANT, "false");
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_ALGO, WSConstants.RSA_SHA1);


    // Set this property if you want client public key (X509 certificate) sent along with document
    // server will check signature using this public key
    msgContext.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
    msgContext.put("password", prop.getProperty(KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_PASSWORD));
    reqData.setMsgContext(msgContext);
    reqData.setUsername(crypto.getDefaultX509Identifier());
    reqData.setUseSingleCert(true);
    reqData.setSigCrypto(crypto);

    final java.util.List actions = new java.util.ArrayList();
    actions.add(new Integer(WSConstants.SIGN));
    CustomHandler handler = new CustomHandler();

    // sign document
    handler.send(WSConstants.SIGN, doc, reqData, actions, true);

    return doc;
}
```

and configuration file:

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=hgaa.ws.crypto.CryptoSmartCard
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.provider=SunPKCS11
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=PKCS11
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=c:/windows/system32/aetpkss1.dll
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.private.password=xxxx
```